# Html image overlaps on the phone

Tags: html, css

I am coding a web page for the first time and thus I have used a template. But when I try to look at the web through my phone the photo I used as logo doesn't fit in the size of the phone (I already have the  line).

I have tried creating a class called logo that wraps the image:

```
<nav class="gtco-nav" role="navigation">
    <div class="gtco-container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                <div class="logo">

                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="GM Arquitectes" width="400" heigth=auto>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-10 text-right menu-1">
                <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Inici</a></li>
                    <li><a href="sobre-nosaltres.html">Sobre nosaltres</a></li>
                    <li><a href="projectes.html">Projectes</a></li>
                    <li class="has-dropdown">
                        <a href="#">Idioma</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="index.html">Català</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Español</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="contacte.html">Contactar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>
```

And then I added the following CSS code:

```
.logo {
    float:left;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .logo {
        max-width:100%;
        float:left;
    }   
}
```

As this media screen seems to manage phone size elements.

The web is already up on gmarquitectes.cat so you can look at it.

Comment: Hi. Please write more code so we can help you with your problem - something that we can replicate. Currently, I can only guess that perhaps your CSS is being overridden by the template.

Comment: Ok, though the original CSS is really long

Comment: This is how it looks on mobile: https://nimb.ws/YQ05Pq Do you want to reduce the size of the logo?

Comment: I see it now. I was not able to see the HTML code on my phone.

Comment: Yes, exactly I would like the logo to fit the phone and the Projects letter to be right under the photos.

Comment: But I am getting lost through so many code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `logo` class as a class for the `<img>` tag not the `<div>` tag that wraps the image since by default you have given the `<img>` a `width=400` HTML attribute.

```
<div>
    <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="GM Arquitectes" width="400" heigth=auto>
</div>
```

Also in your website The CSS Media Query you have mentioned on your question is not shown on your website. Currently on your website, as of this writing, this is what is written:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .logo {
        width: 50px;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

Simply change this to:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .logo {
        max-width: 95%; /* you are going to want to leave some space for the hamburger button. hence the 95% value */
        float: left;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I already this option but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You need to put the `logo` class as a class for the `<img>` tag. Currently, it is still on the `<div>` tag.

Comment: Wow so true. Thanks a lot really, I am just starting and I am not very used to the environement. Do you know why the  Project tap appears so low?

Comment: Perhaps because of some padding/margin issues